# Geometry Nodes - diamond socket to circle socket (multidata to single data)

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to "convert" diamond socket to circle socket (multidata to single data) ? Current node setup produce red warning wire
I'm using **just one point** to determine start location of Mesh Line, but blender see these multidata (i guees)

I'm calling this "Multidata", because of this thread: [Why node socket shape is different (diamond vs circle)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251223/why-node-socket-shape-is-different-diamond-vs-circle)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Attribute Statistic node to get a single value from multiple values:

[image: using attribute statistic node]