# Is there a node wrangler for geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shortcut

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of node wrangler for geometry nodes, so with node wrangler add-on activated and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> a node called viewer appears. The previous solution doesn't show what the current node is doing to the geometry, is there a shortcut that links the actual node with the group output, showing what an individual node and its predecessors is doing?

Comment: did you try shift alt lmb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you go to your add-ons -> node wrangler -> show hotkey list you will see:

[image]

so if you shift ctrl (or alt) LMB on a node, it automatically connects to the output.

Because i am working on a mac...my combination is Shift-Option-LMB.

> if both (shift-alt-lmb and shift-ctrl-lmb) are not working, you should
> check whether these combinations are used for other actions. Then
> delete these other actions to make it work.

Comment: On Windows it works with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>, thank you so much, now it will be easier to understand what I'm doing

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Viewer is used to  preview the values in spreadsheet:

[image]

More about debugging using viewer [in my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259223/geometry-nodes-viewer-node-how-can-i-debug-a-value/259225#259225)

Comment: Online I've seen people showing the geometry output instead of values, do you know something like that?

Comment: Only if you'll connect node to group output...

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it seems like there is a shortcut that I'm missing. Instead to drag the output of the node to the group output, they make it with a shortcut, as the node wrangler in the shader editor